# I am making a macro that needs to move a windowed program

Tags: python, pynput

I am using pynput and so far i haven't figured it out i have tried arrow keys and teleporting the mouse relative to its position and to specified coordinates

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller as KeyboardController
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller as MouseController
import time
keyboard = KeyboardController()
mouse = MouseController()
mouse.position = (-1756, 1079)
time.sleep(0.5)
mouse.click(Button.left, 1)
time.sleep(1.5)
mouse.position = (904, 181)
mouse.press(Button.left)
for number in range (80):
    keyboard.press(Key.left)
    keyboard.release(Key.left)
mouse.release(Button.left)
print("done")
```

Comment: What is the question? What technical issue are you experiencing?

Comment: I'm curious where are you clicking that needs pressing the left key 80 times while pressing the left button of the mouse.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.